# django 1.8 -'ResultView' object has no attribute 'method'

Tags: python, django

I got this error when open "result_list.html", please help correct my code. The logic is when user submit the form it will redirect to this result html. But now I just open this "result_list.html" seperately , it pops up this error.

**url**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^result_list/$',ResultView.as_view(),name='result'),
    url(r'^input/$',InputFormView.as_view(),name='input'),
)
```

**views.py**

```
class InputFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'inputform.html'
    form_class = InputForm

#redirect to result page with submitted form information

    def get_success_url(self):
        return ''.join(
        [
            reverse('result'),    ----redirect to 'result' page
            '?company=',self.request.POST.get('company'),
            '&region=',self.request.POST.get('region')
        ]
        )

class ResultView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'
    model = Result

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(ResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))

        return context

    def get_queryset(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = InputForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                company = form.cleaned_data['company']
                region = form.cleaned_data['region']

                queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region)
                return get_context_data(queryset,request)

            else:
                print form.errors()
        return Result.objects.all()
```

**inputform.HTML Snippet**

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'result' %}">  ----if here correct?
        {% csrf_token %}

        <!--enter company--> 
        <div class="field">
            {{ form.company.errors }}
            <label for="{{ form.company.id_for_label }}">Company:</label>
            {{ form.company }}
        </div>

        <!--select region-->
        <div class="field" >
            <label> Select the Region:
            {{ form.region }}
                {% for region in form.region.choices %}
                     <option value="region" name= "region" id="id_region">{{region}} </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </label>
        </div>

  .......
```

**result_list.html

```
<div class="basicinfo">         <!--form information-->
    <table border="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Company</td>
                    <td>{{company }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td align="left">Region</td>
        <td>{{region}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="result">
    <table  style border="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr> {{sales}}</tr>
    </table>
.....
</div>
```

**Traceback:**

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\list.py" in get
  159.         self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ss\result\views.py" in get_queryset
  91.         if request.method == 'POST':

Exception Type: AttributeError at /result_list/
Exception Value: 'ResultView' object has no attribute 'method'
```

**New traceback**

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\list.py" in get
  174.         context = self.get_context_data()

Exception Type: TypeError at /dupont_list/
Exception Value: get_context_data() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

**New views.py based on suggestion**

```
class InputFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'inputform.html'
    form_class = InputForm

#redirect to result page with submitted form information

    def get_success_url(self):
        return ''.join(
        [
            reverse('result'),    ----redirect to 'result' page
            '?company=',self.request.POST.get('company'),
            '&region=',self.request.POST.get('region')
        ]
        )

class ResultView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'
    model = Result

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(ResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            form = InputForm(self.request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                company = form.cleaned_data['company']
                region = form.cleaned_data['region']

                queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region)

            else:
                print form.errors()
        return Result.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get_queryset method accept only self parameter. If you want to get access to request you must write self.request.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        form = InputForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            company = form.cleaned_data['company']
            region = form.cleaned_data['region']

            queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region)
            return queryset

         else:
             print form.errors()
         return Result.objects.all()
```

Comment: Hi @Dima Kudosh, I changed as you suggest, then it reports "get_queryset() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)", what does it mean?

Comment: `get_queryset` doesn't accept the request as an argument at all. You can access it via `self.request`.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Roseman, if I change to def get_queryset(self.request): if self.request.method == 'POST':................return get_context_data(queryset,self.request), it shows error. Is this where you mean to change?

Comment: No, that's not valid Python syntax. You don't put `request` in the signature at all. `def get_queryset(self)`. Plus, why are you returning the value of `get_context_data`? You should be returning the queryset, not the result of a separate method.

Comment: Hi@Daniel Roseman, I uploaded the new views.py based on you and Dima's suggestion, but after clicking "submit" the form, it couldnn't redirect to "result" page. Am I doing something wroing in the "def get_success_url(self):"? Thanks for your clarification in advance.

Comment: Hi @Dima Kudosh, thank you a lot, but I think we need to remove the "return get_context_data(queryset,request)“ as Daniel suggests.

Comment: Hi @Dima Kudosh, could you please help take a look at my "def get_queryset(self). " part, I suspect there is something wrong there , and that's why I couldn't redirect to the result page after submitting the form. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add return queryset in get_queryset_method

Comment: Hi @Dima Kudosh, I tried both "return queryset" and "return get_queryset_method(queryset), it doesn't work. It could indeed redirect to the url of result page, but it is a blank page with nothing.

Comment: It's return empty page? Can you add to question your result_list.html?

Comment: Hi @Dima Kudosh, please see attached html snippets. Yes, it redirects to an empty page. But if I just put in browser the url of result_list.html, it could open successfully. It just cannot redirect to this page successfuly. That's why I doubt may be in def get_queryset(self).  it's wrong.

Comment: Try to change your inputform.html to <form method="POST">{℅ csrf_token ℅}{{form.as_p}}<input type="submit" /></form>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93367/discussion-between-elena-and-dima-kudosh).